# Alternatives to "Constructive Criticism"

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm a big fan of [constructive criticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism#Constructive_criticism), but I'm afraid that the term has become a cliche - or even a [buzzword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzzword)!

What are some good synonyms for it?

Comment: As an example of what I believe to be constructive criticism, I offer my opinion that *constructive criticism* is not, and never will be, a cliche. It is simply good use of language, conveying exactly what is intended. IMHO the only alternative offered so far that really comes close is *helpful criticism*, but why use an [uncommon phrase](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=constructive+criticism%2Chelpful+criticism&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) when we've already got a more common one?

Comment: Alternatives to Constructive Criticism?  Down Voting.

Comment: @LarsTech: IMHO by definition up/downvotes without an explanatory comment are simply favourable/unfavourable criticism. To be constructive, criticism must *help* the author see what he can do to improve his output.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry, I forgot the smiling sarcasm face.  :-)

Comment: Constructive criticism isn't just a cliche and a buzzword; it's also an oxymoron.

Comment: @Kyralessa: It's possible to be witheringly critical of something without being in the least constructive. Especially if you're just a consumer/customer who's not satisfied with what you just paid for. Often you just want your money back so you can get something better.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think you may have missed my point.

Comment: @Kyralessa: I guess I did. I implied in my first comment that constructive and criticism can (and indeed should) go together. You said it's an *oxymoron:a rhetorical figure in which incongruous or contradictory terms are combined* (i.e. - they can't go together). Which I still disagree with, but I see now that pointing out they *needn't* go together was hardly relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Critique* is less forceful in a negative way than *criticism*.  E.g. as a verb:

> He critiqued the movie script.

That would not come across as unconstructive.  *Critique* as a verb seems quite valuable in this scenario.

Also, there is nothing wrong with using your own phraseology, even if it's not a common expression.  Hence you could say *helpful criticism*, where the *helpful* has more positive force to it than *constructive*, due to the latter's overuse.  There are many other ways to communicate this as well.  For instance, you could say someone **offered some efficacious remarks**.

Answer (score 8):

Simply call it "*feedback*", without trying to qualify it further.

(Works best in business environments; I would not give my wife *feedback*, for example. I would *share* something with her.)

Comment: *Feedback* really just means any reaction, not necessarily constructive criticism. I normally assume it implies a continuous back-and-forth exchange which you'd hope would be constructive, but on the other hand there's not necessarily any implication in *constructive criticism* that the author and the critic are together at any time, or that there will be follow-up after the first critique. In short, *feedback* is quite likely to be a different process entirely.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you are confusing the concept of a "feedback loop" or feedback in a sound system with the meaning I intended: [The return of information about the result of a process or activity; an evaluative response](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/feedback). I meant it as a word that would be completely neutral, so in that sense it is not a true synonum for *constructive* criticism, though.

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly *confusing* the two meanings, though I hope you'll admit it's no coincidence that they both share the same word-form. I'm just saying firstly that feedback/criticism isn't *by definition* constructive, and secondly that I do normally expect such feedback to be part of an ongoing process. Whereas you might get *constructive criticism* in a single letter from a publisher rejecting your blockbuster manque, with no expectation of further interaction.

Comment: ...okay, so that publisher's letter could be called *feedback*. But it still could if all he wrote was *"Your book is rubbish. Don't call to discuss it"*.

Comment: Anyway, regardless of all my nitpicking, I think *review*, and *critique* as a verb imply something done for the benefit of other "users" (audience, buyers, whatever), not the producer (author, director,...). That makes *feedback* the second-best expression (*contructive criticism* being the best, IMHO), so I'm upvoting it. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, *review* is very good, but at the risk of nitpicking further, I see a negative connotation in "critique" (*Critique of Pure Reason*, for example) that makes it a less desirable candidate for a synonym for *constructive* criticism. Otherwise I would upvote "critique", too: without that connotation, it is a very good synonym.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1422/discussion-between-jeffsahol-and-fumblefingers)

Answer (score 4):

I like the word [review](http://thesaurus.com/browse/review?page=3&qsrc=121). Usually, I use the word *suggestions* in the context.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the context and type of comments, but here are some acceptable substitutes:

- Feedback
- Responses
- Advice
- Thoughts
- Reactions
- Suggestions
- Comments

"Constructive Criticism" isn't a terribly descriptive phrase -- it refers primarily to the intentions of the person who delivers it rather than the thing being delivered. Focus instead on the type of comments you're giving or requesting, and use the common name for that specific thing.

Answer (score 1):

If we're sticking with alliteration, how about *actionable advice* or *honest opinion*? *Gut reactions* and *first impressions* are usually pretty honest too.

Answer (score 0):

***Constructive advice*** is a more positive way of saying ***constructive criticism***.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. Could you explain more and provide research for the information you are giving?

Answer (score -1):

My alternative is "Insight through Hindsight". The word "criticism" immediately puts one side in a defensive posture and can destroy any possibility for a positive outcome.

Comment: That has very little of the meaning of **constructive criticism**.  Specifically, criticism is a shared thing, where insight is personal.  If you want to share that insight, your phrase says nothing about that.  A synonym has been asked for, not an entirely different meaning.

Answer (score -1):

I just wanted to post this list I found after reading this old thread. Remember context is the key. You could use any of these words to convey the same idea or meaning depending on how you phrase and intone or inflect.[image]